# Multiple template types

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to have multiple template types in C++?

For example;

```cpp
template<template<typename> class BaseClass>
class MyClass {};

template<class BaseClass>
class MyClass {};
```

And using it;

```cpp
// Using the first template (template<typename> class BaseClass)
template<typename SubClass>
class MyFirstSubClass : public MyClass<MyFirstSubClass> {};

// Using the second template (class BaseClass)
class MySecondSubClass : public MyClass<MySecondSubClass> {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have separate templates with the same name, but you can have a base template and one or more specializations of that class.

```
template<class BaseClass>
class MyClass
{ };

template<class T, template<typename> class BaseClass>
class MyClass<BaseClass<T>>
{ };

template<>
class MyClass<int>
{ };
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of using this with my original code?

Comment: I tried using your code like [this](https://gist.github.com/jackwilsdon/81058b310eeac926815e), however I get the error "wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)".

Comment: You should probably do the second one as `template<typename SubClass> class MyFirstSubClass : public MyClass<MyFirstSubClass<SubClass>> {};`. All the specializations will have to take the same number of parameters as the base template.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. You'll have to have two different template classes:

```
template<template<typename> class BaseClass>
class MyClassA {};

template<class BaseClass>
class MyClassB {};
```